# Substituting variable in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was given following differential equation to solve
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin(x+y)+\cos(x+y)$$
So I substituted 
$$x+y=t$$
Which becomes
$$1+\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dt}{dx}$$
My equation finally becomes
$$\frac{dt}{\cos(t)+\sin(t)+1}=dx$$ 
How do I integrate this??

Comment: According to Wolfram, the answer is $$\ln\left(\sin\left(\frac{x}{2} \right)+\cos\left(\frac{x}{2} \right)\right)-\ln\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{2} \right)\right)+C \\ = \ln\left( \tan\left(\frac{x}{2} \right)+1\right)+C$$ Perhaps you can work backward to see why that is the answer? Or other users might have better suggestions on how to approach this directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying tan substitution $u = \tan(t/2)$

$$
\sin(t) = \frac{2u}{u^2+1}\\
\cos(t) = \frac{1-u^2}{u^2+1}
$$
And finally
$$
dt = \frac{2du}{u^2+1}
$$
Your integral becomes
$$
\int \frac{2}{2u+2}du
$$

Comment: Yay , thanks chinny . integrals are bit troublesome.

Comment: No problems..I am not great but I recognise a few ;).

Comment: Just out of curiosity have you come across this sub I used? Was it something they expect you to know straight off?

Comment: Yes i was expected to know it but you know there are too many of them so i often forget which one to use when.